# Twig parse array and check by key

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to see if an array has a key. The first case returns 2 results 1-5 and , while the second seems to work fine.

Any ideea why is this happening ?

```
{% set options = {'1' : '1' , '1-5' : '5' , '1-12' : '12' } %}
{% set selected = '1-5' %}

Wrong check
{% for k,v in options %}
    {% if k == selected %}    
        {{ k }}
    {% endif %}    
{% endfor %}


Right
{% for k,v in options %}    
    {% if k|format == selected|format %}    
        {{ k }}
    {% endif %}        
{% endfor %}
```

https://twigfiddle.com/c6m0h4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig will compile the "wrong check" in the following PHP snippet:

```
if (($context["k"] == (isset($context["selected"]) || array_key_exists("selected", $context) ? $context["selected"] : (function () { throw new RuntimeError('Variable "selected" does not exist.', 6, $this->source); })()))) {
```

Simplified this becomes

```
if ($context["k"] == $context["selected"])
```

Because the type of `context["k"]` (for the first iteration) is an integer, `PHP` will typecast the right hand part of the equation to an integer as well. So the equation actually becomes the following:

```
if ((int)1 == (int)'1-5')
```

and casting `1-5` to an integer becomes `1`, making the final equation to:

`1 == 1` which evaluates to `true`

---

You can test the fact that first key gets treated as integer with the following `PHP`snippet by the way

```
<?php

$foo = [ '1' => 'bar', ];
$bar = '1-5';

foreach($foo as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key); ## output: (int) 1
    var_dump($key == $bar); ## output: true
}
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/jpVY4K)